# Tableview estimated row height in ios 8

Tags: ios, swift

I am using following code for scrolldown tableview to bottom:

```
let numberOfSections = tableView.numberOfSections()
let numberOfRows = tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(numberOfSections-1)
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: numberOfRows-1, inSection: 0)
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom,
            animated: true)
```

It works well but unless I use the following line, my code is not working properly.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: What are you trying to achive? Are you trying to set the row height?

Comment: I am using message bubbles, row height is important for me because you know if message is long row should expand to height

Comment: Try self.tableView.rowHeight = 44.0

Comment: Doesn't work. Is there a way to use estimated row height with scroll to bottom ?

Comment: have you tried implementing this delegate method: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat

Comment: @DejanSkledar could you give an example for this ?

Comment: Its just func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 44 }

Comment: Nothing changed, still same.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you need to set the row height to automatic dimensions. Check out this article by
http://natashatherobot.com/ios-8-self-sizing-table-view-cells-with-dynamic-type/

To set up your self-sizing cell, just add AutoLayout to your cell, specify your tableView’s estimatedRowHeight, and set the tableView’s rowHeight to UITableViewAutomaticDimension (this will be the default setting in future XCode6 versions).

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 89
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Create a new project and table with dynamic row height. Also try adding other content to a cell to check if the problem has to do with the Automatic feature not being turned on versus the automatic feature not detecting the extra content within its cell. Ray W also has a swift tutorial on dynamic row heights. This is a newer feature and will take some playing with.

Comment: Sometimes it works well but sometimes it doesn't work. I couldn't understand this.